# Left sided limit of an Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis

If $f \in \mathcal R(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$ and $\alpha$ is continuous at $b$, show that

$$\lim_{c \rightarrow b^-} \int_{a}^{c} f \space d\alpha = \int_{a}^{b} f \space d\alpha$$

From the definition of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral we know that $\alpha$ is both monotonically increasing and bounded on $[a, b]$.

And the definition of the left-sided limit is:

$\lim_{x \nearrow c} f(x) = A$ if for every $\varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that $c - \delta < x < c, x \in [a, b] \implies |f(x) - A| < \varepsilon$.

Would showing that $\lim_{c \rightarrow b^-}c = b$ be a first step in solving solving that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Since $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\;d\alpha(x)=\int_{a}^{c}f(x)\;d\alpha(x)+\int_{c}^{b}f(x)\;d\alpha(x)$$
exists and is independent of the limit $c\to b^{-}$, we get
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\;d\alpha(x)=\lim_{c\to b^{-}}\int_{a}^{c}f(x)\;d\alpha(x)+\lim_{c\to b^{-}}\int_{c}^{b}f(x)\;d\alpha(x).$$

Now show that the second limit is $0$, thereby showing
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\;d\alpha(x)=\lim_{c\to b^{-}}\int_{a}^{c}f(x)\;d\alpha(x).$$

Comment: Is that correct?

$\\L(P, f, \alpha) \leq \int f \space d\alpha \leq U(P, f, \alpha)\\$
$L(P, f, \alpha) = \sum_{i=1}^n m_i \Delta\alpha_i = \Delta\alpha \sum_{i=1}^n m_i = (\alpha(b)-\alpha(c))\sum_{i=1}^n m_i = 0$ as $c \rightarrow b^-\\$
$U(P, f, \alpha) = \sum_{i=1}^n M_i \Delta\alpha_i = \Delta\alpha \sum_{i=1}^n M_i = (\alpha(b)-\alpha(c))\sum_{i=1}^n M_i = 0$ as $c \rightarrow b^-$
$\implies 0 = \lim_{c\to b^{-}}L(P, f, \alpha) \leq \lim_{c\to b^{-}} \int_c^b f \space d\alpha \leq \lim_{c\to b^{-}}U(P, f, \alpha) = 0\\$
$\implies \lim_{c\to b^{-}} \int_c^b f \space d\alpha = 0$

Comment: Unless $\alpha$ is uniform, i.e. Lebesgue measure, you can't take it out of the sum like that since it depends on the partition interval (even if your partition is evenly spaced).  In other words, in no circumstance is $\Delta\alpha_{i}=\Delta\alpha$ (whatever the right hand side is) except where $d\alpha=dx.$ Moreover, $\Delta\alpha\neq\alpha(b)-\alpha(c)$ in this situation.  You need to work on your solution, but the general idea is correct.

Comment: Isn't
$$\require{cancel} \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta\alpha_i = \\ \bcancel{\alpha(x_1)} - \alpha(x_0) \\ \bcancel{\alpha(x_2)} - \bcancel{\alpha(x_1)} \\ \bcancel{\alpha(x_3)} - \bcancel{\alpha(x_2)} \\ ... \\ \alpha(x_n) - \bcancel{\alpha(x_{n-1})} \\ = \alpha(x_0) - \alpha(x_n)$$
?

Comment: Of course, but $\sum m_{i}\Delta\alpha_{i}\neq(\alpha(b))-\alpha(c))\sum m_{i}$ unless $m_{i}$ is also independent of $i$ on all partitions (i.e. $f$ is constant). And in any case, it still doesn't give you the right to pull $\Delta\alpha_{i}$ out of the sum since $\Delta\alpha_{i}\neq\Delta\alpha_{j}$ for $i\neq j$ in general unless $\alpha(x)=x$, or $\alpha(x)=\text{constant}$ (in which case the integral is $0$ no matter what $f$ is).

Comment: I see what I did. It's like changing the order of precedence of multiplication and addition. $\sum_{i=1}^n m_i\Delta\alpha_i \neq \sum_{i=1}^n m_i \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta\alpha_i$

Comment: $$\sum_{i=1}^n m \Delta\alpha_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^n m_i \Delta\alpha_i \leq \int f \space d\alpha \leq \sum_{i=1}^n M_i \Delta\alpha_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^n M \Delta\alpha_i$$

That is true, right?

Comment: So 

$$0 = m(\alpha(b)-\alpha(c)) =  m\sum_{i=1}^n \Delta\alpha_i = \sum_{i=1}^n m \Delta\alpha_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^n m_i \Delta\alpha_i \leq \int f \space d\alpha \leq \sum_{i=1}^n M_i \Delta\alpha_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^n M \Delta\alpha_i = M\sum_{i=1}^n \Delta\alpha_i = M(\alpha(b)-\alpha(c)) = 0 \text{, as }c \rightarrow b^-$$
$$\implies 0 \le \lim_{c\to b^{-}} \int_c^b f(x) \space d\alpha \le 0$$
$$\implies \lim_{c\to b^{-}} \int_c^b f(x) \space d\alpha = 0$$

Is that correct? I'm pretty bad at this.

Comment: Yes, that's fine, since $\alpha$ is left continuous at $b$ and $|f|$ is bounded by the assumption $f\in\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$.